# Big number entered as an input automatically changes. How do i stop this?

Tags: c, binary, integer, ascii

I'm trying to make an encryption algorithm without using arrays or strings because those are the rules of the assignment i'm working on. Because of this i have been having a lot of issues trying to figure out a way to go with the algorithm.

Basically the user has to enter a 24 bit binary text. For example: '010000010100000101000001'
and the algorithm is supposed to do a XOR operation with the key '01000001' and separate the bits of the resultant in 3 8 bit parts, and find the decimal value of the binary code of the 8 bit parts. Then translate them each to ASCII characters.

The way i thought about this was to define an integer with the value for 1000000000000000000000000(24 zeros) so the zeros of the input wouldn't disappear on the front. However because the number is big the input of '010000010100000101000001' becomes '947938113'

I asked the program to print the input to see: (input is '010000010100000101000001')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

int count,tot,cho,key=1010000010100000101000001,temp,encry_tex;
char;

printf("Which base will you use to enter text (base 16/2)?");
scanf("%d",&cho);

temp=1000000000000000000000000;

if (cho==2)
{
   printf("Please enter the text to encrypt: ");
   scanf("%d",&encry_tex);

    tot=temp+encry_tex;  /* this part is not important, that's how the 
                            program was supposed to go but they don't mean 
                          anything to the question im asking. */
    tot=tot+key;

   printf("%u",encry_tex);
}
}
```

If i enter an input such as 10001001, it still gives me 10001001, the problem appears when the numbers get big.

How can i fix this?

Comment: On most systems, an `int` is 32 bits, and has a maximum value of about 2 billion. A 64-bit unsigned number has a maximum value of about 1.8e19. The number assigned to `temp` has 24 zeros after the one, so it doesn't fit in any type that a C compiler supports. You need to a big integer library for that. The alternative is to enter the number in hex, or as 3 separate 8 bit binary numbers.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you about `temp=1000000000000000000000000;`?  It should.  If it doesn't, you need more compiler warning options (though none should be necessary to get a warning from that), or you need to get a better compiler.  And while you're learning C (I'm still doing that, 30+ years later), assume the compiler knows more C than you do.  If it deigns to warn you, treat it as a bug.  And make sure it gives you as much help as possible.  If you use GCC, `gcc -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror` is a decent starting point.  I use those options and more before I'm willing to run a program.

Comment: You could also read one character at a time with `getchar()` and build the number with shift `<<` and OR `|`.

Comment: If you're trying to enter binary numbers, investigate whether your compiler supports `0b` as a prefix (like `0x` for hex).  Some compilers do; some don't.  The notation is part of modern C++ (C++11 or C++14, IIRC).  It is not a part of standard C.

Comment: Another way is to define the binary array as a string, and convert that to an integer type with `strtol()` or `strtoll()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are correct, but in the first line of the question: *"without using arrays or strings because those are the rules"*

Comment: _without using arrays or strings_ --> Note that `"Please enter the text to encrypt: "` is an array and a string.

Comment: My guess is that the goal of the assignment is to teach the student about the ASCII to digit conversion, as well as using shift and OR to assemble a binary number. And I have a feeling this was discussed in detail in the most recent lecture.

Comment: The binary number can be built from char-by-char input in a similar way as for decimal: `number = number * 2 + (digitchar - '0');`

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <math.h>`  The OPs code does not use any of the contents of that library header.   It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. avoids 'literal folding'
2. performs the desired functionality
3. removes unneeded `#include` statements
4. cleanly compiles
5. performs the desired functionality
6. properly checks for I/O errors
7. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( void )
{
    //int count;
    int tot;
    int cho;
    //int key=1010000010100000101000001;
    int key = 0x01414141;
    //int temp;
    int encry_tex;


    printf("Which base will you use to enter text (base 16/2)?");
    if( scanf("%d",&cho) != 1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input number base failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //temp= 0b1000000000000000000000000;
    int temp = 0;
    temp |= (int)0x80000000;

    if (cho==2)
    {
        printf("Please enter the text to encrypt: ");
        if( scanf("%d",&encry_tex) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input of number to encrypt failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        tot=temp+encry_tex;  /* this part is not important, that's how the 
                                program was supposed to go but they don't mean 
                              anything to the question im asking. */
        tot=tot+key;

       printf("%u",encry_tex);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Note:  the `cho` is completely useless, unless the code will input a char string and convert that string.   In general, the user determines the data format via a leading `0x` or `0b`